# Unable to load the dzetsaka plugin in qgis 3.4.2

Tags: windows-10, python

Previously it worked in a lower version of qgis. After updating to a newer version its not working.

Couldn't load plugin 'dzetsaka' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

```
AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/VVSK/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\dzetsaka\dzetsaka.py", line 54, in 
    from sklearn import datasets
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 335, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/VVSK/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\dzetsaka\__init__.py", line 35, in classFactory
    from .dzetsaka import dzetsakaGUI
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/VVSK/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\dzetsaka\dzetsaka.py", line 56, in 
    pip.main(['install','-U' , 'scikit-learn'])
AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'


Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.4.2-Madeira Madeira, 22034aa070 

Python Path:
C:/Users/VVSK/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\leastcostpath
C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/VVSK/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/VVSK/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python37.zip
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/VVSK/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/VVSK/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\go2streetview
C:\Users\VVSK\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\go2streetview\res
C:\Users\VVSK\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins
.
C:\Users\VVSK\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\tuflow
C:\Users\VVSK\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\tuflow/forms
C:\Users\VVSK\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\tuflow
C:\Users\VVSK\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\tuflow/forms
C:\Users\VVSK\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\tuflow/forms
C:/Users/VVSK/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\timeseriesviewerplugin
C:\Users\VVSK\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\timeseriesviewerplugin\site-packages
```

Comment: Go speak to the developers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Nicolas, the developper of dzetsaka.

Sorry for the bug, I just made in december an update to automatically install sklearn (the library used to have algorithms such as Random-Forest, KNN, and SVM).
Indeed, in some cases it won't work, so I just make an update right now in order to prevent errors when installing sklearn (and so not install this wonderful library).

However if you want to use RF or SVM algorithms, please read how to do here : https://github.com/lennepkade/dzetsaka.

I submitted dzetsaka V3.4.2 to Qgis, so it should be available very very soon in Qgis 3.

Next time if you have a bug, please leave a message here : https://github.com/lennepkade/dzetsaka/issues